# Set IAM Role Description

Tags: aws-cloudformation

In the AWS Console there is an option to set a description for an IAM Role. How do you do this with CloudFormation? The documentation does not state how to do this. So far I have tried.

```
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Description: My Description
```

Resulting error: No actual CF error, but this description does not show in the Console

```
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Description: My Description
    Properties:
      .....
```

Resulting error: "Encountered unsupported property Description"

```
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      Tags:
        Key: Description
        Value: My Description
```

Resulting error: "Encountered unsupported property Tags"

```
Resources:
  MyRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Tags:
      Key: Description
      Value: My Description
    Properties:
      .....
```

Resulting error: "Encountered unsupported property Tags"

Comment: Thank you to the brave person who down voted my question without even leaving a comment. I read the documentation and it didn't appear there was a supported description property. However the lack of this feature is not consistent with AWS own best practices of tagging and keeping good track of your resources.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update November 2019:**

The `Description` field is now supported in CloudFormation.

```
Properties: 
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument: Json
  Description: String               <--- Here
  ManagedPolicyArns: 
    - String
  MaxSessionDuration: Integer
  Path: String
  PermissionsBoundary: String
  Policies: 
    - Policy
  RoleName: String
  Tags: 
    - Tag
```

Comment: I suspected it wasn't supported, which is disappointing something so simple is not available out of the box.

Comment: CloudFormation often updates over time. Feel free to click the Feedback button to ask for the feature!

Comment: [This feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-description) is now supported in CloudFormation

Answer (score 2):

Tested and can confirm John Rotenstein's answer remains the best option as of 29/Mar/2019. Sometimes updates can sneak in without making the documentation, but not in this case unfortunately.

(Would have preferred to put this as a comment however the reputation requirement is a pain)

Edit:
July/2019 - Still no update, however this can be done through the SDK

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it has been added as of September 3rd, 2019. Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-description) part of the AWS CloudFormation docs.